# .NET: Redirect from domain and subfolder to new domain, retaining path and querystring, using httpredirect in web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, http-redirect

I am trying to setup a domain redirect as part of a domain migration. My caveat is that the site I am redirecting from is in a subfolder of a wider domain. I also need to retain the rest of the path and query string.

I need to setup a redirect in web.config that achieves the following:

- https://www.domain1.com/mysite to https://www.domain2.com
- https://www.domain1.com/mysite/users  to https://www.domain2.com/users
- https://www.domain1.com/mysite/api/getData?inputParam=45 to https://www.domain2.com/api/getData?inputParam=45

**I've tried:**

`<httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="https://www.domain1.com$V$Q" httpResponseStatus="Temporary" exactDestination="true" />`

but this doesn't remove the "mysite" subfolder. It redirects to https://www.domain2.com/mysite instead of https://www.domain2.com

I've also tried creating a rewrite rule but I cannot figure out a working input and regex.

TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could go with two rules in URL Rewrite:

```
<rule name="remove-my-site">
  <match url="^mysite/([/_0-9a-z-]+)"/>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}"/>
</rule>
<rule name="domain1-to-domain2">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="domain1.com" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.domain2.com/{R:0}" />
</rule>
```

You will not make it with httpRedirect. It's for much simple re-writes.

You can also check [Application Request Routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing) documentation for configuring a reverse router with IIS.

What we might have missed is this step:

> Enabling Reverse Proxy functionality

Comment: Worked a charm. Thank you!
Edit: This doesn't appear to work for httprequests to our api endpoints. This gives 404.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? What is the behavior you are getting? Is it maybe some CORS issue? If your domain is A and you are redirecting with XHR to B, then it makes sense to get a CORS error.

Comment: If I hit an endpoint such as https://www.domain1.com/mysite/api/getData?inputParam=45 in the browser address bar then it redirects as expected.

But if I hit the same endpoint via postman or through an HttpClient request in code, to simulate how the api will actually be consumed, then the response is a 404 Not Found.

Comment: Try to add Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * response header from your api. My guess is that this is what blocks you.

Comment: I added [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")] on the endpoint and deployed to domain2 but this had no effect.

Comment: So, to help me undestand: When you write the url in your browser, the redirect happens and you get your data correclty. When calling from XHR you are getting a 404 error in your console. Right?

Comment: Have you tried to enable the Application Request Routing (if it's not already?). There are also some good ideas in the posted link in the answer.

Comment: I've discovered that the Authorization header is not being passed through the redirect. This is prompting the api to `return NotFound();`. So now I need to figure out why the header isn't being passed, and if I can get it passed.